# Инкрементация переменной в течении определенного времени php

Tags: php

Учу php. Есть задача: Каждая бактерия делится на 2 в течении минуты. Нужно задать рандомно время и начальное количество бактерий и показать сколько их зареспаунится за это время.
Я написал такой скрипт:

```
$time = rand(0, 60);
// $time = 2;
$baktStart = rand(1, 50);
// $baktStart = 1;
$i = 0;
while ($i++ <= $time) {
    echo ++$baktStart;
}
```

Но мне кажется что он неправильно работает так как на при задаче стартовых значений по времени 1, по стартовому количеству бактерий 2 вместо 6 я получаю 234.

Подскажите собственно как правильно написать данный скрипт не используя никаких функций, кроме rand?

Comment: Вероятно вы получаете не 234, а 2, 3, 4 потому что ваш цикл на каждой итерации печатает следующее число, без пробелов или других разделителей

Comment: Действительно, вы правы, однако скрипт все равно работает неккоректно, даже если он печатает все подряд - должно быть 2 4 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал скрипт через `for`, вы должны умножать количество на 2, а не добавлять по 1, то есть вот так:

```
<?php
$time = rand(0, 60);
$baktStart = rand(0, 60);

$count = $baktStart;
for ($i=0; $i < $time; $i++) { 
    $count *= 2;
}
var_dump($count);
```

Можно сделать так же с `while`, суть вы поняли.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, также нашел свою ошибку в подсчетах

Answer (score 1):

> Каждая бактерия делится на 2 в течении минуты

Это означает, что каждую минуту количество бактерий удваивается

Таким образом код будет такой

```
$time = rand(0, 60);
$baktStart = rand(1, 50);
$i = 0;
while ($i++ <= $time) {
  $baktStart *= 2
  echo $baktStart . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Или без цикла

```
$time = rand(0, 60);
$baktStart = rand(1, 50);
echo $baktStart * (1 << $time);
```

Comment: а что такое .PHP_EOL?

Comment: Символ конца строки `"\n\r" для` Windows и `"\n"` для Linux